# Is there a possibility to change restart policy of podman container?

Tags: centos, podman

Is there a possibility to change container restart policy using podman? We can set policy during creating container `podman run --restart always`, but how to change it when the container is created?

Using docker we have `docker update` command which allows us to do so. Unfortunately there is no `podman update` command. Can it be done? Or do I need to create a new container?

Answer (score 4):

when using  podman you should create a systemd service that will manage podman container.

1. create systemd file "/etc/systemd/system/containername.service"

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=your container
>
> [Service]
> Restart=always
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman start -a containername
> ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman stop -t 2 containername
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=local.target
> ```

2. run command:

> systemctl daemon-reload

3. enable service to start at boot

> systemctl enable containername.service

4. restart service

> systemctl restart containername.service

You can also add some other restart systemd parameters like:

```
RestartSec (Configures the time to sleep before restarting a service), StartLimitInterval (seconds service is it not permitted to start any more),  StartLimitBurst
```

for more details check man pages:  "man systemd.service"

Comment: See also [Podman Quadlet](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Podman#Quadlet) for augmented systemd container services. Avoids details in `ExecStart=`/`ExecStop=` in favor of more specialized unit properties. Use [`[Container]` in `*.container` unit files](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-systemd.unit.5.html#container-units-container). Put the unit file in, for example, `~/.config/containers/systemd/` for rootless usage. Quadlet also supports other Podman unit file types, with unit dependencies between them.