# Fail to stop running container with non root account via podman

Tags: podman

I ran into very weird situation with `podman stop/kill` as `non-root` account.  I can neither stop nor kill the container.

I was able to stop/kill immediately when I build image + create/start a container as `root`.

Only delta/change I can think of is, I used `systemd` to keep this container running after the server reboot yesterday as `non-root`.

Target container is `tomcat` and `rhel 8` server.

With `stop`

```
podman stop tomcat

WARN[0010] StopSignal SIGTERM failed to stop container tomcat in 10 seconds, resorting to SIGKILL
tomcat

podman ps

CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                           COMMAND     CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                   NAMES
03719b688b7d  localhost/tomcat:latest                  About a minute ago  Up About a minute  0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp  tomcat
```

With `kill`

```
podman kill tomcat

tomcat

podman ps 

CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                           COMMAND     CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                   NAMES
035241ccaccf  localhost/tomcat:latest                  4 seconds ago  Up 5 seconds  0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp  tomcat
```

With `container rm -f`

```
podman container rm -f tomcat

WARN[0010] StopSignal SIGTERM failed to stop container tomcat in 10 seconds, resorting to SIGKILL
tomcat

podman ps

CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                           COMMAND     CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                   NAMES
22627de7f882  localhost/tomcat:latest                  5 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp  tomcat
```

One thing I noticed was container ID was keep changing after running `podman ps` against `tomcat` container. I thought it should be consistent?

I'd appreciate your advice.

=== update ===

I observed that I can't access an application deployed to tomcat web container from a browser. I was getting 404 error.

When I **forced** to remove `image` then no container is returned from `podman ps`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out when I created container-tomcat.service file yesterday, I set `restart policy` as `always` inadvertently.

Once I changed it to `no`, I was able to run `stop/kill` just fine.

```
[Service]
Environment=PODMAN_SYSTEMD_UNIT=%n
Restart=no
...
```

The clue I got was from [Is there a possibility to change restart policy of podman container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162259/is-there-a-possibility-to-change-restart-policy-of-podman-container)